# Tomcat: Does HTTP persistent connection keep connector thread busy?

Tags: tomcat

When a client establishes a persistent HTTP connection with Tomcat (and Jax-RS), does that occupy a Tomcat server thread for the duration of the connection? Would it be more performant to use asynchronous servlets on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

A tomcat thread is consumed throughout the duration of the HTTP connection (caveat below) but not the actual underlying TCP connection. It might sound confusing but the part that is persisted when it comes to HTTP persistent connections is the underlying TCP connection.

Caveat: if you're using NIO there may be times throughout the duration of the HTTP connection that no tomcat threads are "consumed" (blocking).